# Traceback (most recent call last) - Python

Tags: python, flask

I am a very beginner in the flask environment..

this is main.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Helloworld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {"data": "Hello QQ"}

api.add_resource(Helloworld, "/helloworld")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

text.py file

```
import requests

BASE = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"

response = requests.get(BASE + "Helloworld")
print(response.json())
```

When I was run text.py, had these error..

[image]

Please tell me the error and why it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route in your code says `"/helloworld"` but you are doing `"/Helloworld"` in your `requests` call and I'm pretty sure that part of your URL is **case sensitive**, at least in this example.